# Spring REST Docs: How to output PDF instead of HTML? Unresolved directive

Tags: asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I read through the documentation for Spring REST Docs and was able to generate an HTML file from the snippets, by adding another execution block to the plugin I can generate a pdf as well:

```
<execution>
    <id>output-pdf</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <backend>pdf</backend>
        <doctype>book</doctype>
        <attributes>
            <snippets>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippets> 
            <icons>font</icons>
            <pagenums/>
            <toc/>
            <idprefix/>
            <idseparator>-</idseparator>
        </attributes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

The problem is that the generated pdf doesn't contain any of the snippets generated by Spring REST docs, instead in its place:

```
Unresolved directive in api-doc.adoc - include::{snippets}/request-parts.adoc[]
Unresolved directive in api-doc.adoc - include::{snippets}/response-body.adoc[]
Unresolved directive in api-doc.adoc - include::{snippets}/response-fields.adoc[]
```

Looks like it's not finding the location of the snippets so they are not getting rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are already close. Please make sure that you add asciidoctorj-pdf and asciidoctorj as dependencies to asciidoctor-maven-plugin. The following Maven snippet shows this setup. This configuration generates both HTML and PDF output. It can be reduced to either one by removing the other execution block.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
    <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-alpha.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
            <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-docs</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <backend>html</backend>
                <doctype>book</doctype>
                <sourceHighlighter>highlightjs</sourceHighlighter>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-pdf-docs</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <backend>pdf</backend>
                <sourceHighlighter>coderay</sourceHighlighter>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This setup is working for me. I don't have a Gradle example at hand at the moment.

Comment: Are you using Spring Rest Docs too? I am able to get a PDF with just this dependency in my plugin: spring-restdocs-asciidoctor

The problem I have now is that everywhere in the pdf where there should be a snippet I see
Unresolved directive in XXX.adoc - include::{snippets}XXX.adoc[]

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spring Rest Docs. The additional config that I have is 

    <configuration>
        <attributes>
            <snippets>${snippetsDirectory}</snippets>
        </attributes>
    </configuration>

and I have <snippetsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-snippets</snippetsDirectory> as a propery.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I have that setting too, but it's still not working. You can see above for an update to my question which shows the config that I'm using.

Comment: You don't need the spring-restdocs-asciidoctor artifact in your plugin?

Comment: The problem was I was using the 1.5.0-alpha.17 version of asciidoctorj-pdf, changing it 1.5.0-alpha.16 worked!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Those issues are not easy to find.